# Android 11 Camera not working after cancel the option

Tags: android, android-webview, android-camera, android-camera2

I am opening the image choose option from the android webview app. The camera clicks event not happening further if I click on the device back button after opening the camera & files selection option. The issue is only in Android 11 and all other versions it's working fine after clicking the device back button.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            writeLog("Web Frame -->" + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].
                    getLineNumber() + " --> Camera onActivityResult Version R and Greater -->  requestCode -->  " + requestCode);
            if (requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mFilePathCallback == null)
            {

                writeLog("Web Frame -->" + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].
                        getLineNumber() + " --> Camera onActivityResult   requestCode --> NULL ");
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
                return;
            }

            Uri[] results = null;

            // Check that the response is a good one
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                writeLog("Web Frame -->" + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].
                        getLineNumber() + " --> Camera onActivityResult  -->  RESULT_OK  ");


                if (intent == null) {
                    writeLog("Web Frame -->" + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].
                            getLineNumber() + " --> Camera onActivityResult   data   -->  null  ");

                    // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                    if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {

                        writeLog("Web Frame -->" + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].
                                getLineNumber() + " --> Camera onActivityResult   mCameraPhotoPath   --> not  null  ");

                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                    }
                } else {
                    writeLog("Web Frame -->" + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].
                            getLineNumber() + " --> Camera onActivityResult   DATA   --> NOT  null  ");

                    String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                    writeLog("Web Frame -->" + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].
                            getLineNumber() + " --> Camera onActivityResult   DATA   --> NOT  null dataString "+dataString);


                    if (dataString != null)
                    {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                        writeLog("Web Frame -->" + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].
                                getLineNumber() + " --> Camera onActivityResult   dataString   --> NOT  null  ");


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        writeLog("Web Frame -->" + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].
                                getLineNumber() + " --> Camera onActivityResult   dataString   --> NULL  ");

                        results = new Uri[]{pictureUri};


                        //results= pictureUri.getPath();


                    }

                }

                mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
                mFilePathCallback = null;

            }
            else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {

                //if (requestCode == file_req_code) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed");
              //  return;

               // mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);


                if (requestCode == file_req_code) {
                    if (null == file_data)
                        return;
                    Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
                    file_data.onReceiveValue(result);
                    file_data = null;

                }
                //}
            }
            writeLog("Web Frame -->" + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].
                    getLineNumber() + " --> Camera onActivityResult   Length   -->   "+results.length+" result "+results[0].toString());













        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {

            writeLog("Web Screen -->"+ Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].
                    getLineNumber()+" Camera onActivityResult--> Inside Version Q or Less");
            Uri[] results = null;
//Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Result.."+intent,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            /*-- if file request cancelled; exited camera. we need to send null value to make future attempts workable --*/
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                if (requestCode == file_req_code) {
                    file_path.onReceiveValue(null);
                    return;

                }
            }


            /*-- continue if response is positive --*/
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == file_req_code) {
                    if (null == file_path) {
                        return;
                    }

                    ClipData clipData;
                    String stringData;
                    try {
                        clipData = intent.getClipData();
                        stringData = intent.getDataString();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        clipData = null;
                        stringData = null;
                    }

                    if (clipData == null && stringData == null && cam_file_data != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{
                                Uri.parse(cam_file_data)
                        };
                    } else {
                        if (clipData != null) { // checking if multiple files selected or not
                            final int numSelectedFiles = clipData.getItemCount();
                            results = new Uri[numSelectedFiles];
                            for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                                results[i] = clipData.getItemAt(i).getUri();
                            }
                        } else {
                            results = new Uri[]{
                                    Uri.parse(stringData)
                            };
                        }
                    }









                }
            }
            file_path.onReceiveValue(results);
            file_path = null;
        } else {
            if (requestCode == file_req_code) {
                if (null == file_data)
                    return;
                Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
                file_data.onReceiveValue(result);
                file_data = null;

            }
        }


    }
```